# How to calculate available audio frequencies in an array list created from waveform

Tags: javascript, audio, calculation

I'm working with song files to create *audio-visuals* videos, so I extract audio information from every frame and I need to know which frequencies are playing in the current data-chunk that I have extracted from the current frame to manipulate other stuff.

[A waveform example obtained with my script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deH82.png)

I understand how audio waves works, also I know how multiple frequencies looks in the same sound (such the previous image that represents a bass with a hit hat in the end of the audio-chunk). But I can't create a function to get an estimation of available frequencies in that waveform (stored in a array). My brain is currently fried.

Note: I was working under JavaScript and I have used [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext) to extract information from the audio file, but I can't get frequencies data, I just get a waveform. I tried to use [AnalyserNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode), but
in every tutorial or documentation that I saw the AnalyserNode requires to reproduce the audio in real-time to get frequencies data and, as I said, I extract chunks that represents every frame of the video and It will work in a cloud server.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution, and I will answer my own question if anyone would have the same problem. Remember, **I only want to get frequencies (and then get spectrum data) from every frame of a song file.** So I had to stop looking for the frequencies of the previously obtained samples data to take a few steps back (please see the question to understand this last part).

I found an alternative to [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext), the [OfflineAudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext). With AudioContext, you need to play audio files in realtime to get spectrum data (tones), but with OfflineAudioContext you can save much time because it process all file data as fast as possible by rendering the audio file. I will say that WebAudioAPI is really confusing and I tried several times after get the expected result, but I finally got it.

Below you will find the "final code" to obtain the spectrum-data for every frame (depending of declared fps) of an audio. Also, you can see what you can do with the data obtained with the next data manipulation video result.

[Video Result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uMBUpPdZ21birCng_l-roOjw0V8UiJx0/view?usp=sharing) (Sorry, I can't upload videos to StackOverflow, so you would need to download the result video from Google Drive)

### Javascript

It will returns an array of spectrum-data of every frame.

[WARNING] This code isn't compatible with Firefox, because it uses OfflineAudioContext.pause() and OfflineAudioContext.resume() functions ([see more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext/resume)).

```
let $audioCtx = new ( window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext )( ) ;
let $audioOff = null ;
let $analyser = null ;
let FFT_SIZE  = 512 ;

     fetch( $data.file_url )
          .then( response    => response.arrayBuffer( ) )
          .then( arrayBuffer => $audioCtx.decodeAudioData( arrayBuffer ) )
          .then( async ( audioBuffer ) => {
            window.$audioBuffer = audioBuffer ;
            return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
              $audioOff  = new window.OfflineAudioContext( 2, audioBuffer.length, audioBuffer.sampleRate ) ;
              $analyser  = $audioOff.createAnalyser( ) ;
              $analyser  . fftSize = FFT_SIZE ;
              $analyser  . smoothingTimeConstant = $data.fps === 24 ? 0.16 : $data.fps === 29 ? 0.24 : 0.48 ;
              $analyser  . connect( $audioOff.destination ) ;
              var source = $audioOff.createBufferSource( ) ;
                  source . buffer = audioBuffer ;
                  source . connect( $analyser ) ;
              var __data = [ ] ;
              var fps    = $data.fps || 24 ;
              var index  = 0.4 ;
              var length = Math.ceil( audioBuffer.duration * fps ) ;
              var time   = ( ( 1 / fps ) ) ;
              var onSuspend = ( ) => {
                return new Promise( ( res, rej ) => {
                  index  += 1 ;
                  var raw = new Uint8Array( $analyser.frequencyBinCount ) ;
                  $analyser.getByteFrequencyData ( raw ) ;
                  __data.push( raw ) ;
                  if( index < length ) {
                    if( time * ( index + 1 ) < audioBuffer.duration ) 
                      { $audioOff.suspend( time * ( index + 1 ) ).then( onSuspend ) ; }
                    $audioOff.resume( ) ;
                  } return res( 'OK' ) ;
                } ) ;
              } ;
              $audioOff.suspend( time * ( index + 1 ) ).then( onSuspend ) ;
              source.start( 0 ) ;
              console.log( 'Decoding Audio-Spectrum...' ) ;
              $audioOff.startRendering( ).then( ( ) => {
                console.log( '[✔] Audio-Spectrum Decoded!' ) ;
                return resolve( __data ) ;
              } ).catch( ( err ) => {
                console.log( 'Rendering failed: ' + err ) ;
                throw { error : 'Get audio data error', message : err } ;
              } ) ;
            } ) ;
          } )
          .then( async ( spectrumData ) => {
            /* DO SOMETHING WITH SPECTRUM DATA */
            /* spectrumData[ 0 ] is the first frame, depending of established fps */
            /* spectrumData[ 1 ] = 2nd frame ... */
          } ) ;
```